# A simple Card Game

Tags: probability

In a card game, we remove the Jacks, Queens, Kings, and Aces from a deck of ordinary
cards and shuffle them. You draw one of these cards. If it is an Ace, you are paid a dollar
and the game is repeated. If it is a Jack, you are paid two dollars and the game ends; if it is a
Queen, you are paid three dollars and the game is repeated; and if it is a King, you are paid
four dollars and the game is repeated. What is the expected amount of money you will win
from playing this game?

- So I'm having trouble understanding this question, a standard deck had 52 cards and removing the rest living me with 16 cards right?

Comment: Yes, it seems there are $16$, though it would work the same with $4$

Comment: If the cards aren't replaced, then they would not be the same game.